# When do you use fopen instead of open?

Tags: c, file-io, fopen

I don't find any difference through test.

What's the key to decide on this?

Answer (score 12):

`fopen` is a portable interface that any C environment should provide. Also, its result is a buffered stream (`FILE*`) that can be used with the convenient `stdio` functions.

`open` is a Unix/POSIX-specific interface. Its result is a bare (unbuffered) file descriptor, which has to be used with low-level system calls. It does allow some more fine-grained control over I/O (see the list of flags in the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)), so sometimes you might want to `open` a file and then perhaps [`fdopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopen.html) it to get `stdio` and buffering.

Comment: As indicated in your links, open is a POSIX standard interface, not just unix.

Comment: @new_perl: you use `fopen` unless you have a very good reason not to do so. `open` is harder to use and not very portable.

Comment: It's not harder to use, it's just not portable.

Comment: @zvrba: file descriptors are harder to use then streams for anything but binary I/O; you need to include more headers to get the right operations; and `open` takes a variable number of arguments, making it hard to debug if you pass the wrong number of them or the wrong flags.

Comment: open also exists in the Windows C RTL, but is slightly different to the POSIX one.  For example you cannot open a directory using it.